# Difference between read and write seek time

Tags: hard-drive

Is there any difference between seek time for read and write request?

I tried testing seek time by measuring how long does it take for two requests, one in the beginning and one near the end of the disk (therefore, they should be in the different cylinders). For write, it takes much longer for the sequence of requests to finish compared to the read. Is it because of the seek time for write is longer? Or is it because of another factor, e.g. transfer time?

Here, I attach a write per read latency to size data. As it can be seen that in small request size (which transfer time should be small and disk seek time will affect more to the io time), the write latency is almost 300x the read latency.

[image: write per read to size comparison]

Thanks

Comment: This implies a low-level test. What tool are you using? Off the top of my head, I might say that writes could take longer if you are not writing to a contiguous region. That could require multiple seeks. So you need to ensure your tests do not require crossing boundaries and also that they do not require padding. There may also be bookkeeping overhead associated with a write operation (metadata, ACL etc).

Comment: I am using fio. Yes, that is indeed part of the question, why writes could take longer in a non-contiguous region? Does read not require multiple seeks or the other aforementioned factors?

Comment: 1) it is really above my pay grade (so to speak); 2) what I do know is that it will vary quite a bit from HD to HD and FS to FS. I know that enabling Access Control Lists can increase IO time (microsecond; reads and writes) by orders of magnitude. I expect, with nothing to quote, that file metadata ("bookkeeping ") could be avoided entirely for a read.

Comment: Good question. Me coming late to the party but could you give any specific numbers, also could you provide the disk model? Is it a desktop setup or some specialized storage?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov thanks for your interest, I have added a new numerical data to my post. I am using remote disk and it is currently offline so I couldn't check, but I believe that it is a normal desktop disk setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a little broad and unclear. 
I’m not familiar with this “fio” tool you mention,
and a quick glance at [its web page](http://freecode.com/projects/fio)
didn’t reveal any details regarding how it works (i.e., *what* is it measuring).

- As duDE said, in principle, the seek time —
  the time required to move the I/O head(s) from the cylinder
  where they are to the cylinder where you want to do an I/O operation —
  should be independent to the operation that you want to do
  at the target cylinder.  I believe that it is common
  for a disk driver to issue two separate commands — seek and then read,
  or seek and then write — so the disk *doesn’t even know*
  whether it’s a seek-for-read or a seek-for-write.

But, as I said in my first paragraph, I don’t know what “fio” is measuring. 
I don’t know how a program could measure actual seek time
without having kernel probes. 
It might be measuring the time for an I/O operation at the API level.

- Even at the hardware level,
  a write operation might automatically be followed by a read of the same data,
  to verify correctness.
- At the hardware level, if you have redundant storage (like RAID),
  where the same data are maintained on two or more independent drives,
  typically the I/O head on one drive will tend to linger
  at a low-numbered cylinder (e.g., 0.25×MAXCYL),
  while the I/O head on the other drive will tend to linger
  at a high-numbered cylinder (e.g., 0.75×MAXCYL).  A read operation
  will go to the drive whose head is closer to the target cylinder,
  so the most it will need to seek will be 0.25×MAXCYL,
  while the write operation will go to both drives,
  so it may need to seek up to 0.75×MAXCYL.
- At the operating system / filesystem level,

  - A read may or may not update a file’s access time. 
    Some systems disable this altogether. 
    Others might only set a flag
    (e.g., in the relevant memory-resident inode, or equivalent)
    that the file has been read; the disk-resident inode
    might not get updated until some time later (asynchronously).
  - A write

    - will quite likely require updating the file’s modification time.
    - If you are *extending* the file
      (rather than just overwriting data *near* the end), it

      - will require the file size to be changed (i.e., in the inode), and
      - may require allocating block(s) from the free list (or equivalent),

    and it will probably not be possible to defer these activities.
- If you are using an old file for your testing,
  and you have defragmented the disk since the file was created,
  but you have extended the file since then
  (even if you are not extending the file *in* these tests),
  it may be that the beginning of the file is stored on a contiguous region,
  and the end of the file is not. 
  But the only implication I can see of this is that
  accessing the front of the file may be faster than accessing the end. 
  I don’t see how this could cause a difference between read and write.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there is just one [seek time](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3558/seek-time):

> Seek time is the time taken for a hard disk controller to locate a
>   specific piece of stored data. Other delays include transfer time
>   (data rate) and rotational delay (latency).
>
> When anything is read or written to a disc drive, the read/write head
>   of the disc needs to move to the right position. The actual physical
>   positioning of the read/write head of the disc is called seeking. **The
>   amount of time that it takes the read/write head of the disc to to
>   move from on part fo the disk to another is called the seek time.**

Comment: While the physical movement takes a similar amount of time, there are slight differences on some drives, and big differences in actual use due to the interaction of caches and tolerances and so forth.